# A session had already been started - ignoring session_start() Xampp

Tags: php

```
<?php
if($_SESSION['IS_LOGEDIN'] == 'Y')
{
header("location:index.php?page=home");
exit();
}
?>
```

I have problem guys, i have this login code and this error when I wanna go in that page.

> A session had already been started - ignoring session_start().

I tried to make the code in this way but when I want to go on the page, doesn't want to load:

```
<?php
   if(!isset($_SESSION['IS_LOGEDIN']) == 'Y')
    { 
        session_start(); 
 header("location:index.php?page=home");
    exit();
    } 
?>
```

What's the solution?

Comment: Have you destroyed the session when they log out?

Comment: If you've included `session_start();` inside an included/required file, then that could cause it. You should put `session_start();` at the top though. Plus this `if(!isset($_SESSION['IS_LOGEDIN']) == 'Y')` you should be using 2 conditionals, not one. Check if not set, `&&` if equals to.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is flat-out wrong:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['IS_LOGEDIN']) == 'Y')
   session_start()
```

You start your session **AFTER** you try to test a value that's (presumably) in the session. As well, `isset()` returns a boolean true/false. It'll never return a string, and it will **NOT** return whatever value may be set in the variable you're testing. So basically you've got `if (true/false == 'Y')` which makes no sense.

You probably want something more like this:

```
session_start()
if (!isset($_SESSION['IS_LOGEDIN']) || ($_SESSION['IS_LOGEDIN'] != 'Y')) {
    header('....');
}
```

"if the user has never logged in or is not logged in, then redirect".

Comment: Or it's reverse equivalent `if (isset($_SESSION['IS_LOGEDIN']) && ($_SESSION['IS_LOGEDIN'] == 'Y')){ // do something }else{ // do something different }`, which is probably what the OP wants to achieve. It's a bit unclear as to what the OP does want to achieve though. They posted two different code blocks; which one is the good/bad, or keeping both is anybody's guess. *A session had already been started* usually means there's another copy of `session_start();` somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
    <?php
session_start(); //must be at the start of the page
        if(!isset($_SESSION['IS_LOGEDIN']) or empty($_SESSION['IS_LOGEDIN'])) {
        $_SESSION['IS_LOGEDIN'] = 'Y';
        header("location:index.php?page=home");
    exit();
        }
    ?>
```